# dynamically determining gcc version of any dynamic library built from C/C++ source

Tags: c++, gcc, dynamic-library

I have got a abc.so lib from somewhere, while using gcc4.4.3 I got error that this abc.so is incompatible type. Any idea how to find the version of this lib.

Comment: It it like a wrong 32bit/64bit type?

Comment: Is it unix? If so, you can check the file's format with the ``file`` command. It could just be the wrong architecture.

Comment: What was the error given by GCC exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix :

List the strings from the binary, and simply grep the GCC version :

```
 strings -a <binary>| grep "GCC:"
```

This will give you the GCC version used to build the binary. But I'm not really sure it's what you want to know.
You can also get more informations about the binary by using `readelf -h <binary>`

Comment: I am trying to link a dynamic library and getting this error : "file not recognized: File format not recognized". I am not very sure what is going wrong. So trying my luck with gcc version. But no use. Any idea what should I do.

Comment: What is the output of `file <your library file>` ?

Comment: abc.so : : ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

Comment: strings -a <binary>| grep "GCC:"
is working fine. but I think problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure the binary has been compiled for your architecture ? What's your system arch ?